# Автоматическая смена статуса по таймеру

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Никак не могу сформулировать запрос к БД, чтобы всем записям, у которых dates (дата платежа) старше месяца, заменить в поле `status = 'inactive'`. Что-то типа такого: `UPDATE table SET status = 'inactive' WHERE dates <= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH);`, но у меня `dates` в `INT(11)` в UNIX.

Comment: По поводу апдейта. Ответ на первый вопрос — во втором вопросеб только я ошибся с числами. 

Этот запрос обновляет в таблице пользователей поле `paid`.

Если текущее время минус то время, что уже записано в этом поле, меньше *месяца* (т.е. ещё действует Экспертный режим), пишем остаток+текущее время = время_предыдущей_оплаты + 2 * *месяц*.

Если больше, т.е. сейчас бесплатный режим, то просто пишем текущее время.

Comment: Математика многих в краску вгоняет : )

Мы отмечаем время _начала_ оплаченного периода. Два раза оплатили = 2 месяца от первой оплаты.

Comment: Никак не могу сформулировать запрос к БД, чтобы всем записям, у которых dates (дата платежа) старше месяца заменить в поле status = 'inactive'.
Что-то типа такого: 
 
    UPDATE table SET status = 'inactive' WHERE dates <= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH);

Но у меня dates в INT(11) в UNIX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вместо 1/0 храните в БД timestamp момента, когда юзер стал Экспертом.

У просто-новичков там 0 по умолчанию. Когда юзер заходит, сравнивайте текущее время `time()` со значением из БД. Если меньше месяца прошло (`31*24*60*60` секунд), считайте юзера Экспертом. Иначе - Новичком.

Comment: Мну нужно подвязать оплату сюда. Подойдет ли этот способ? То есть чел оплатил, через месяц его "подписка" закончилась. Плюс статус нужно выводить словами в профиле пользователя и других страницах сайта.

Comment: Конечно, подходит: пришла оплата - прописали юзеру текущую дату-время в поле БД. Сам недавно так делал. Учтите ещё момент коллизий: может оплатить до истечения срока дейстующей оплаты. Или сразу за 2 месяца проплатить. Тогда нужно вычислять неиспользованный остаток времени и прибавлять его к текущему времени, прежде, чем писать в базу.

Comment: Я думаю, коллизий с проплатой за 2 месяца можно избежать, прописав фиксированную сумму в поле оплата (та же робокасса). А вот с проплатой раньше срока, да... Может быть беда...  
Я думаю, что значение можно обновлять в БД на текущее, но тогда сгорят "неиспользуемые дни". Как быть?

Comment: А показывать статус — ну это же элементарно: при первой загрузке, если в сессии ничего нет, смотрим БД и обновляем её если надо, и сохраняем в сессию статус юзера. Оттуда же и берем на последующих страницах.

Comment: У меня статут не текущего пользователя, а просто любого пользователя. Как мне вытаскивать из БД и сравнивать?

Comment: Как вы различаете пользователей – они же как-то логинятся? Вот на этом этапе и их статус проверяйте/устанавливайте.  С оплатой раньше срока я же написал. Примерно так можно:

    UPDATE users 
    SET paid = IF (
      (UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - paid) < 67685760,
      paid + 135371520,
      UNIX_TIMESTAMP()
    )

Comment: Подскажите, что за беда - делаю запрос на добавление в БД строки, но вместо unix вносятся одни нули? Тип поля timestamp

Comment: Сделайте поле вместо timestamp типом Int(11)

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите эти видео - [*Скачать(.zip)*](http://ruseller.com/lessons/les1762/demo.zip) и [*Создание автоматизированных запросов в MySQL*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rIt1JjMCAfc)

Comment: Видео не работает. (( Напиши название видеоурока, с первой ссылки.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=alPA2hrup9c&feature=youtu.be

Comment: Тоже интересное видео. Имеет право на существание. Спасибо.